# UNION ALL tables if @@rowcount from first SELECT yields less than 10 rows

Tags: sql, database

I'm trying to do a stored procedure to be used by a search mechanism.

The way I want it to work is to first do a `SELECT` with `LIKE TOYOTA%`.  After that, if the results yield less than 10 results, I want it to append or `UNION ALL` with another `SELECT` that has a `LIKE %TOYOTA%`.

So Basically, this is what I'm looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM CARS
WHERE CARS.MAKE LIKE '@searchQuery%'

IF(@@rowcount < 10)
   BEGIN
      UNION ALL
      SELECT *
      FROM CARS
      WHERE CARS.MAKE LIKE '%@searchQuery%'
   END
```

The only problem is that I can't do this - it won't let me use `UNION ALL` before or after the `IF`.

I'm doing this because I want to always have at least 10 results as much as possible.  If I have less, then I want to fill the remaining slots with records that may have the name TOYOTA somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this to always get 10 results:

```
SELECT top 10 *
FROM CARS
WHERE CARS.MAKE LIKE '%@searchQuery%'
order by (case when cars.make like '@searchQuery%' then 0 else 1 end);
```

To strictly do what you want (get all that begin with the search query and then pad out to 10 if less than 10), you can use window functions:

```
select c.*
from (SELECT c.*,
             row_number() over (order by (case when c.MAKE LIKE '@searchQuery%' then 0 else 1 end
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM CARS c
      WHERE c.MAKE LIKE '%@searchQuery%'
     ) c
 where c.MAKE LIKE '@searchQuery%' or seqnum <= 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a table variable I think...

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar table(
    CarID int NOT NULL,
    Puertas int,
    Ruedas int,
    FechaDeSalida datetime);
```

You should declare it exactly equal to the CARS table. Then you do

```
SELECT @MyTableVar=*
FROM CARS
WHERE CARS.MAKE LIKE '@searchQuery%'
```

Now in the variable, you have your query result. Finally:

```
IF(@@rowcount < 10)
   BEGIN
      SELECT *
      FROM @MyTableVar
      UNION ALL
      SELECT *
      FROM CARS
      WHERE CARS.MAKE LIKE '%@searchQuery%'
   END
```

Sorry for my bad english! Hope this help!

Comment: This worked for what I needed it for!  The only problem, since I do it a couple times, it seems to kill performance just a little bit. Nothing too major though.  Thanks!

Comment: @MarioGuzman Great! You can choose a correct answer so the question belong closed! Anything else, you can make another question. You are welcome!